# Join two HDMI monitors ubuntu 20.04

Tags: hdmi, mirrors

I am using an HDMI splitter and two monitors + the laptop monitor (a total of 3).
Ubuntu 20.04 detect all of them, but two (the HDMI) **only work as a mirror**. If I go to **Settings->Displays** I only can find two monitors (1 HDMI and the laptop monitor) why? How can I join all of them?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I join all of them?

**You can't.**

What the splitter does is to take ONE video output and send the exact same output to TWO different monitors. The computer "sees" only one.

In a nutshell everything describe in the question is exactly what's expected to happen and it has nothing to do with the OS. This is about hardware design.